# Directive that binds to form input blur event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to have a directive for my validation messages that takes the name of the form input being validated and then displays itself if the named form input is invalid. For the sake of good UI, I want this to only happen after the input is blurred. Here's a Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/qLSsCHpAPLdZsCPG8iaf

Obviously, `ctrl[attr.tgValidates]` isn't giving me an object I can bind to (although it is referencing the correct field), but I'm not sure how to properly select the element I do want. jqLite doesn't have great support for selectors, so it's a tricky to do what I want without pulling in all of jQuery. I guess I could also pull in `$document` and select off that, but I'm wondering if there's a better, more Angular way to approach this?

Comment: You can compile stuff into Angular elements: `angular.element(element);`  
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element

Comment: What is the `element` that you are passing in? I know `angular.element` can be used with certain selectors, but it isn't able to select elements by name.